# question about global nonzero section of bundle

Tags: vector-bundles, transversality

Suppose $M$ a manifold with dimension $m$ and $E$ a vector bundle whose based manifold is $M$.

Assume $\mathrm{dim} E$ is $2m+1$, by Transversality theorem, seems I can obtain a global section without zero point, because we have a transversal map $s:M \to E$  but $2\times \mathrm{dim}M <\mathrm{dim}E$, so $s$ will not intersect to the zero
section.

It's surprising, do I misunderstand something? If it's true, is there any natural concept to explain it? Thanks!

Comment: You certainly obtain a map $s : M \to E$ which does not intersect the zero section, but why is the map $s$ a section? It is true that if $\operatorname{rank} E > \dim M$, then $E$ admits a nowhere-zero section. This follows from obstruction theory.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thanks for your comment! Yes this map may not a section, but there is a theorem(page 63 of kosinski's book differential manifold) says that, for every smooth map from based manifold to the total space,we can find a section transver to this map, which can be used to prove the Transversality theorem. Take the smooth map as zero section we will get a transversal section.

Comment: That's correct. My comment intended to point out that the usual transversality theorem is insufficient to prove the claim you made. As you point out though, the theorem from Kosinski's book gives the desired result.